# How much are tag warnings used?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, statistics, tag-warnings

Although I'm reasonably experienced on Stack Exchange (8+ years of activity, 40 sites with 500+ reputation, 247k total rep) and have been a diamond moderator on one site for some 5 years, today I saw a [tag-warning](/questions/tagged/tag-warning) for the first time.

Are there any statistics available for the various Stack Exchange on how many tags have tag warnings attached to them?  Is this something that can be queried with the Stack Exchange Data Explorer?

Comment: I know this can be found in our staff-only local SEDE instance... Though I'm guessing it might not be accessible in the public SEDE instance because the contents of the blocklist (which is the same system that tag warnings also use) are generally only visible to mods (not the public).